# How to print a string static member of a class with `yield` from a class method

Tags: python

I am really new to python, so this might be really easy.
I want to print two strings defined in a class as static members with a class method that yields each string.
This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys


class test:
    str1 = "Hello"
    str2 = "World\n" #"\n" is needed for the example

    def printMe(self):
        yield test.str1
        yield test.str2

hello = test()

print "Testing initiated:"
sys.stdout.write(hello.printMe())
sys.stdout.write(hello.printMe())
```

This is the output:

> sys.stdout.write(hello.printMe()) TypeError: expected a character
>   buffer object

Comment: Why are you using `sys.stdout.write`? Can't you use `print`?

Comment: You may also want to put a `while True:` at the top of `printMe` if you could be printing the values over and over. As it is now, the function will be exhausted after two prints, and you'll get a `StopIteration` condition if you try to print further.

Comment: @xndrme: I wanted to avoid the new line at the end that print injects

Comment: @Chris you can avoid that using `end=''` in `print` check the edit of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use a generator function, read about the `yield` keyword [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

```
import sys


class Test: 
    def __init__(self): # it's possible to initialise these attributes in the __init__ method, so they are created on class instantiation(when you did hello = Test())
        self.str1 = "Hello"
        self.str2 = "World\n" #"\n" is needed for the example

    def printMe(self):
        for i in [self.str1, self.str2]:
            yield i 


app = Test()

print "Testing initiated:"

for i in app.printMe():
    print i # is there a reason why you can't use print?
```

If however you want to print the lines one at a time, at specific points in the code, like in your loop you mentioned in the comment:

```
gen = app.printMe()
```

then every time you want to print:

```
gen.next()
```

this triggers the next yield statement. The generator function effectively 'holds'/remembers it's place until you call next again, until all the yield statements have been yielded.

Comment: I was just in a rush that's why I didn't capitalize the first letter of a class. So you create a tupple to be used in the range of the for-loop, right? But what if I don't want to print the two strings in once, but after another iteration of a loop (that the print is inside)?

Comment: actually, you could use the two yield statements that you had above. But the list I have there(not a tuple) works too.

Comment: Yes a list, sorry for the mistake, I've just started learning python. (I've extended my above commend)

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
for line in hello.printMe():
    print line
```

But really there are a lot of easier ways than using yield statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but I'm using `print`, hope this helps you:

```
class test:
    str1 = "Hello"
    str2 = "World\n" #"\n" is needed for the example

    def printMe(self):
        yield test.str1
        yield test.str2

hello = test()

print "Testing initiated:"
out = hello.printMe()
print(out.next(),end=' ')
print(out.next(),end=' ')
```

Comment: For forward compatibility, better to write `next(out)`.

Answer (score 0):

using yield turns your function into a generator.  If this is really what you want, you will need to iterate over the generator to get the values:

```
gen = hello.printMe()
sys.stdout.write(gen.next())
sys.stdout.write(gen.next())
```

or better:

```
for prop in hello.printMe():
    sys.stdout.write(prop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your printMe method is a generator function, which returns an iterable. You need to iterate over it to get the results :

```
for item in hello.printMe():
    print item
```